# Typo: "对" read "代"

Tags: vocabulary

第18章 第二具尸骨的身份 https://www.vodtw.com/book/6042/chapter/5020723.html: 1st line of 3rd paragraph contains the following phrase:我不该对替她隐瞒, some users hold the view that 对 may be a typing error, in fact that 代 would make better sense, see e.g. BKRS: 代替: "instead", e.g. 代替他写了信

Answer (score 1):

我不该对替她隐瞒 is ungrammatical

Depending on the context, the correct sentence should be either 我不该**对**她隐瞒 (I shouldn't hide the fact **from** her) or 我不该**替**她隐瞒 (I shouldn't hide the fact **for** her)

Also, 对 is not a typo of 代 because the sentence "我不该代替她隐瞒" (I shouldn't hide it in her stead) is illogical. As if she didn't have to hide something from people because you would hide it in her stead. The problem is that "she didn't need to hide it" implies she is disclosing it.

**Edit:**

Based on the context, the correct sentence is 我不该**替**她隐瞒

我不该对替她隐瞒 is a typing mistake

Comment: phrase follows 我当初就该和警方说的，i.e. 我不该对替她隐瞒  some users wonder whether possibly "not talking to the police" may mean hiding the facts from the police and thus favoring her, i.e. "instead of her" in the sense of "helping her"

Comment: i.e., 我不该替她隐瞒  would make good sense because of context, users still wonder how to explain the appearance of 对, that is the question is, how could such an error possibly arise

Comment: such an error possibly arises when the typer typed 我不该对她隐瞒 and realizes it should be 我不该替她隐瞒. He should have highlighted 对 and typed 替 over it . Maybe due to a bad mouse move, he ended up adding 替 after 对 instead. And the sentence became 我不该对替她隐瞒

Comment: The most common method of typing seems to use the Wubizixing keyboard and the codes for 对 and 代 respectively are cf and wa which seems to suggest to some users that mistyping one for the other may be very unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

Please read Tang's answer. My answer does not have much new value.

In Chinese, there is no composite word "对替".

People would not say 我不该**代替**她隐瞒. Instead, people would say (a) 我不该**替**她隐瞒; and (b) 我不该**对**她隐瞒. But (a) is different from (b) in meaning.

(a) 我不该**替**她隐瞒. - I should not hide her wrongdoing in the benefit of her. (for her).

(b) 我不该**对**她隐瞒. - I should not hide what I did (or the things that I knew) from her. (not telling her when facing her, or in front of her)

From your link, I think the contents would be like this, 我当初就该**和**警察说实话的. 我不应该**对**警察撒谎, **替**她隐瞒她的行为.

**替**她隐瞒 = **为**她隐瞒 (for her). You cannot use **代替** (substitute her position) in this sentence.

**代替** means completely substituting a person or the role of he or she. For example,

她今天没来上班, 我**代替**她收银. - She did not come to work, therefore I will be in her position as the cashier.

You can simply say 今天我**替**她收银.

By the way, when you say 我**代替**他写了信, that can be ambiguous because it can be interpreted as,

(1) I wrote the letter for him because he is illiterate. (or he has no time to write.) 我**替**他写了信

(2) I wrote the letter without his knowledge. (This is rare though)

Comment: Is this a criticism of BKRS? Being ambiguous in the sense that there could be different reasons for writing the letter does not seem to detract from the validity of BKRS's example of the use of 代替.

Comment: 代替他写了信 is ambiguous, it could mean "impersonated him and wrote the letter" or "take up his duty of writing the letter"

Comment: Similarly, 代替她隐瞒 could mean "substitute her identity and hide the fact" or" take up her duty of hiding the fact" . Neither makes sense in this context

Answer (score 0):

In the story, the lead character feels betrayed after hiding the fact from the police "**for**" a person/the wrong-doer who has later turned against him/her. In this case, the sentence "我不该**替**她隐瞒 - I shouldn't lie/hide the fact for her)" is anticipated/correct.

However, if the story-line changes to that the wrong-doer at first denied the fact but later confessed to the police, after the lead character committed perjury in her favor, the sentence "我不该**代替**她隐瞒 - I shouldn't **instead** hide the fact to the police for her" is then correct.

In any case, the sentence "我不该**对替**她隐瞒" is wrong, as there is no such word - "对替" in Chinese. However, note that "我不该**对**她隐瞒 - I shouldn't hide from/lied to her" is a valid sentence, but it does not fit well with the story.